How to correctly extract Numbers from String using regex in Python?
I am trying to extract Numbers from the string only where it ends with Numbers or Decimals
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ["Absolute Neutrophil Count","Absolute Lymphocyte Count 2.9",
                       "Absolute Neutrophil Count 10.2","ESR (Modified Westergren) 8",
                        "Free Triiodothyronine (FT3) 3.59",
                        "Free Triiodothyronine FT4 4.53"]})

df


                         Names
0   Absolute Neutrophil Count
1   Absolute Lymphocyte Count 2.9
2   Absolute Neutrophil Count 10.2
3   ESR (Modified Westergren) 8
4   Free Triiodothyronine (FT3) 3.59
5   Free Triiodothyronine FT4 4.53

Desired Extraction Results:
0  Missing/None
1  2.9
2  10.2
3  8
4  3.59
5  4.53

I was trying below  code but that is not giving the desired results.
df.iloc[:,0].str.extract(r'^(.*?)\s*(\d\.?\d*)?$') #  '\d+\.\d+'

                           0      1
0   Absolute Neutrophil Count     NaN
1   Absolute Lymphocyte Count     2.9
2   Absolute Neutrophil Count 1   0.2
3   ESR (Modified Westergren)     8
4   Free Triiodothyronine (FT3)   3.59
5   Free Triiodothyronine FT4     4.53

Please use dataframe form of structure in Answer and .extract otherwise sometimes answers here with re and strings work but when I try to apply them on df then it becomes something else.

This question is similar to: Reference - What does this regex mean?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The following regex pattern seems to be working here:
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$

This matches an optional ending integer/decimal.  The updated Pandas code would look like:
df.iloc[:,0].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?$')

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern being used:

( capture

\d+ an integer
(?:\.\d+)? followed by optional decimal component


) close capture
$ end of the string


I am getting all NAN in the outwith with this pattern in code.

Updated answer, I misread your question.

Earlier with my code df.iloc[:,0].str.extract(r'^(.*?)\s*(\d\.?\d*)?$') I was getting two columns in the result but with your answer code I am getting only 1 column. Is it possible to get two columns separated with your code ??

Use: df.iloc[:,0].str.extract(r'(.*?)(?: (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?)?$') ... check the regex demo here: https://regex101.com/r/jv9axD/1

This works perfectly as I was looking for. thanks alot :)

The regex you used doesn’t isolate numbers at the end of the string, which is why the results aren’t coming out right. Try using (\d+(\.\d+)?)(?=\s*$) to extract decimal or integer numbers that appear at the end of the string.

It wasn't giving me right results for example from 2.9 it extracted only .9 from 10.2 extracted only .2. But thanks for trying to help :)

To address your question, you can make the following changes in the code:

Assign your extracted values in one variable


ans = df.iloc[:,0].str.extract(r'^(.?)\s(\d.?\d*)?$') #  '\d+.\d+'


Access only first index only


ans[1]

Please refer to the image below for additional clarification.
https://i.sstatic.net/Qs9JGpfn.png
